# Use Google Cloud Pub/Sub with Android and Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an Android application that uses Firebase services.

I want this app to **publish** to a Google Cloud [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) topic.

**Only [Firebase-authenticated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) users** should be able to publish. They do not need to subscribe to the topic.

How can I set this up in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the best way but I think, you can create a Firebase Functions and you can do authentication there. And then the functions publish data from Pub/Sub topic.

Comment: Thanks! The approach looks good. Maybe someone else could help validate it? Just to know if there are any other methods.